# How To clear Previous Signal R Web Socket Connections?

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I am creating a chat application using signal r, and using ajax call when switching from one chat to another chat. The issue which i am facing is, whenver i switch from one chat to another chat using ajax call, it creates a new web socket connection. and one message sent the number of time the web socket connection is created. So how can i clear previous connections with ajax call. as when i refresh the page only a single web socket connection is present.

Comment: Please provide some code to better explain your issue.

Comment: i can post the image of multiple web socket connections. just let me know if there is any way of clearing those previous connections using ajax call